# how to serve dynamic files in django?

Tags: python, django

I know there are many answer already, but unfortunately I failed to find a solution on them.

Basically I am trying to serve image files stored at server|`/srv/post/users/folder/PIMAGES/ACTIVE/image.jpg` to client, but with the configuration I have in my settings.py file, I am getting an http `404` file not found error.

my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/post/'
MEDIA_URL = '/post/'
```

and then if I refer to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/users/folder/PIMAGES/ACTIVE/image.jpg`

I just get 404 page not found.

Answer (score 0):

@whocaresz you are referencing your MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL incorrectly, when you specified MEDIA_ROOT as `srv/post/` then your image.jpg should be in `post` directory and to access it go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/image.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

for future students, I also had to add a static entry to my project `urls.py` file as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^thisischanged/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('someapp.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

or `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` at the end.